# Remove ShaperRenderer offset

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx

I want to use libgdx ShapeRenderer to mock my graphics but i get a small nevertheless annoying mismatch of coordinates. As mentioned at [libgdx wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Coordinate-systems), screen coordinates range: (0,0) (lower left corner) to (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-1, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-1) (upper right corner).

Here is a code sample of what i'm trying to do:

```
public static final int APP_WIDTH = 160;
public static final int APP_HEIGHT = 120;

private SpriteBatch batch;
private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
private Texture texture;

...

public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    if (DEBUG_MODE) {
        shapeRenderer.setAutoShapeType(true);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        shapeRenderer.begin();
        shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, APP_WIDTH - 1, APP_HEIGHT - 1);
        shapeRenderer.end();
    } else {
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(texture, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

And the result i get:
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KywEv.png)

As you can see, texture (160x120) is drawn exactly like it should be but rectangle (that was drawn with shapeRenderer) has -1 x-axis offset. 
Of course, I can just draw everything at x+1 but maybe I'm doing something wrong and there is a way to make coordinates match?

Comment: Since shape renderer is rendering lines, it draws exactly on pixels. The effective coordinate of a pixel in OpenGL is in the center of a pixel, not the edge. So I think you need to add 0.5f to your coordinates passed to ShapeRenderer.

Comment: You are right, seems like I need to dive into OpenGL :)

shapeRenderer.rect(0 + 0.5f, 0 + 0.5f, APP_WIDTH - 1, APP_HEIGHT - 1);
works fine.
So should i always add +0.5f to x and y when I want to render something with shapeRenderer?

Comment: Only when drawing lines, not filled shapes. It's a different rendering path.